# Simson line problem with understanding

Tags: geometry

Lines $k, l, m$ intersect in one point $O$, and point $P$ doesn't lie in any of them. Points $A, B, C$ are orthographic projection of point $P$ on lines $k, l, m$ Prove that orthographic projection $P$ on lines $AB, BC, CA$ are collinear.

[image]

First step of solution:

Points $A, B, C$ lie on circle with diameter $PO$. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** What’s the converse of Thales's theorem?

Observe that Thales's Theorem claims the following

> Let $\omega$ be a circle with diameter $AB$ and let $C$ be another point on the circumference. Then $$\angle ABC=90°$$

There is a visual proof that might help you understand why this is true. In fact, consider

[image]

Thus $$\color{purple}{\angle OAC+\angle ACO}+\color{blue}{\angle OCB+\angle  CBO}=180°\implies \angle ACB=\color{purple}{\angle ACO}+\color{blue}{\angle OCB}=90°$$

---

You might also want to prove it using this amazing property of cyclic quadrilaterals (I.e. quadrilaterals inscribed in a circle)

> A quadrilateral is cyclic if and only if opposite angles add to $180°$. Why so?

The proof of this statement uses a similar trick as in Thale's theorem.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand how those hints could help me.

Comment: Observe that the triangles $\triangle PAO,\triangle PBO, \triangle PCO$ are right triangles. What's the the consequence?

Comment: Using above theorem we got what I was asking for! Thank you for your patience.